# Where to find Pius IX's 1871 Apostolic Letter, "Qui Ecclesiae Suae"?

Tags: catholicism, resource-request, alphonsus-liguori, pius-ix

The following quote is from Pope Bl. Pius IX's declaring St. Alphonsus Liguori as a Doctor of the Church:

> “One can in fact assert that there has not been one error even in our times which Alphonsus, at least in great measure, did not fight against.” (Source: *Qui Ecclesiae Suae*, Apostolic Letter, Pius IX, Rome, 1871.)

Can anyone provide me with a link to the papal document *Qui Ecclesiae Suae*?

I thought it would be an easy thing to find, but I was mistaken.

Comment: Yes, it's surprisingly hard.  I tried and have *yet* to find it.  Even tried finding a document containing the declaration with possibly different title, but came up empty *so far*.  But I'm an optimist.

Comment: @GratefulDisciple I don't think Literature SE will help with this one :-)

Comment: No, you're right.  For this Q, the buck stops here.  Other avenues we can try while continuing Google / library search: 1) Contact the Vatican; 2) Email websites that specialize in Vatican documents such as https://www.papalencyclicals.net/ (I sent the inquiry to them); 3) Wait until @Geremia picks it up; he has proven quite resourceful.

Comment: @GratefulDisciple Yes;  Geremia might know where this document is hiding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's in the [*Acta Sanctæ Sedis*](https://www.vatican.va/archive/ass/index_en.htm) (1856-1908):

- [ASS 06 [1870-71]](https://www.vatican.va/archive/ass/documents/ASS-06-1870-71-ocr.pdf), pp. 320-4.

Comment: Many, many thanks for providing this information. I apologize once again for the delay in responding as my accounts, as I previously mentioned, were hacked.